# Heroku: code=H18 "Server Request Interrupted" with minimal Java Server

Tags: http, heroku

The http server works locally with 'heroku local web' but not on heroku cloud. I always get the error: code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=GET

Here is the class, it is basically a hello world server. Not much can go wrong here:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("PORT")).orElse("8080"));

        System.out.println("Server started: http://localhost:" + port);
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("client connected: " + socket);
            new Thread(new ClientConnector(socket)).start();
        }
    }

    public static class ClientConnector implements Runnable {
        Socket socket;

        ClientConnector(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter(os);

                // Read request
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("< " + line);

                    line = reader.readLine();
                }

                // print response
                String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
                        + "Content-Type: text/html\n"
                        + "Content-Length: 11\n"
                        + "\n"
                        + "hello world";
                printwriter.println(response);

                System.out.println("sent response");
                os.flush();
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a full example of the log, the request is read and response sent:

```
:00 heroku[router]: sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=GET path="/" host=hidden-brook-63920.herokuapp.com request_id=936ffe14-adc2-4773-966e-44b1ce4b60d0 fwd="202.58.193.226" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=503 bytes=72 protocol=https
app[web.1]: client connected: Socket[addr=/10.41.207.114,port=17962,localport=9405]
app[web.1]: < GET / HTTP/1.1
app[web.1]: < Host: hidden-brook-63920.herokuapp.com
app[web.1]: < Connection: close
app[web.1]: < Cache-Control: max-age=0
app[web.1]: < Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
app[web.1]: < Total-Route-Time: 0
app[web.1]: sent response
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the HTTP response has to be with `\r\n` and not `\n`. RFC 2616 requires CR LF. The local network is more tolerant than the Heroku routers.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2:

> HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker for
> all    protocol elements except the entity-body (see appendix 19.3 for
> tolerant applications). The end-of-line marker within an entity-body
> is defined by its associated media type, as described in section 3.7.
>
> ```
>    CRLF           = CR LF
> ```